# Set a class static property via construct

Tags: php, singleton

I currently have the following code:

```
class User {
    private static $_db;

    public function __construct () {
        self::$_db = Database::getInstance()->getConnection();
    }

    public static function addUser ($name, $username, $password) {
        // Define Values
        $name = ucwords(trim($name));
        $username = strtolower(trim($username));
        $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        // Define Query
        $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (name, username, password) VALUES(:name, :username, :password)";

        // Prepare Query
        $preparedQuery = self::$_db->prepare($query);

        // Execute Query
        $preparedQuery->execute([
            ':name' => $name,
            ':username' => $username,
            ':password' => $password
        ]);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to set a class property with my database connection through a construct. Issue is that I want to be able to access the `addUser()` method anywhere in the script by simply calling `User::addUser()`. Is there a way I can set a static property via a construct or is there a better way to go about accessing my database?

Comment: Why would you use a constructor to setup static state?

Comment: Why do you want `$_db` to be static, out of curiosity?

Comment: Currently in order to access my database I have to repeat the following line in every method that needs to access it or pass it in the arguments: `$db = Database::getInstance()->getConnection();`. I feel it would be better to have a classwide accessible variable that I can use instead of repeating myself all over.

Comment: google dependency injection. Use either a factory, or DIC, or just pass the database connection to the static method

Comment: @bassxzero I would argue that OP is properly injecting his/her dependencies with constructor injection. 
@Blake I'm sure you don't need to make `$_db` static, but every instance of the class doesn't need a separate connection to the database, so static does indeed make sense.

Comment: So what is not working? Looks fine to me.  Personally I prefer using a singleton for my DB but that is just me.  And the only argument I would make is to separate the DB connection from the User class .... Actually it looks the like the DB is likly a singleton anyway, so there is no need to set it in the class at all.  Simply `$DB = Database::getInstance()->getConnection();` in the method would be enough for localization.

Comment: @Andriko13 if DI is giving a class, method, or function the requirements it needs and the `addUser` method doesn't have access to a database connection but needs it, then how is he properly injecting his dependencies?

Comment: He injected the dependency into the class, but not the static method. I suppose you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct is only called when a new instance of the class is created. Since `addUser()` is a static method, and thus a new instance is **not created**, your constructor will not get called and the static `$_db` variable will never get initialized.

I would add create a static method that returns the connection to the db, and you can use that everywhere throughout your code. For example:

```
class User {

private static $_db;

public function __construct () {
    // construct
}

public static function getDB () {
    return Database::getInstance()->getConnection();
}

public static function addUser ($name, $username, $password) {
    // Define Values
    $name = ucwords(trim($name));
    $username = strtolower(trim($username));
    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    // Define Query
    $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (name, username, password) VALUES(:name, :username, :password)";

    // Prepare Query
    $preparedQuery = self::getDB()->prepare($query);

    // Execute Query
    $preparedQuery->execute([
        ':name' => $name,
        ':username' => $username,
        ':password' => $password
    ]);
}
}
```

If you wish to continue using a static property, you can create a static setter for the property (you would need to call this method at least once before calling `addUser`):

```
public static function setDB () {
    self::$_db = Database::getInstance()->getConnection();
}
```

Comment: That seems like a pretty good method that could work. For non static methods I'll just call a construct on them and set a `private $_db`

Comment: You can tailor the code to your needs. Keep in mind that non static methods can still use `self::getDB()`, so there is no need to duplicate the code.

Comment: So essentially static methods can only reference static methods and properties, non-static methods can still access static methods and properties?

Comment: You can think of it that way, yes.

Comment: Great! Now I have a final kind of off topic question that maybe you could help me with. Where should I instantiate my  objects? Should I have a file specifically for that propose or should I just create them when I need them? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. You instantiate objects whenever you need an instance of the class. It could be in a different file or not.

Comment: For example, sometimes I need a single instance accessible everywhere but am not sure where I should instantiate it. I was thinking of having a file called `instances.php` and including that in my `init.php` file. But for single instances I should just instantiate it and work off that variable when I need it?